# Why did a "USING BTREE" appear in "CREATE TABLE" with mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was examining my database tables, and something appeared I cant explain that:

```
CREATE TABLE  `challenges` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `KIND` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TITLE` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DESCRIPTION` text NOT NULL,
  `DATEAT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `OWNER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SOLVEDREPLAY_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Index_2` (`OWNER_ID`),
  KEY `Index_4` (`DATEAT`),
  KEY `Index_3` (`SOLVEDREPLAY_ID`) **USING BTREE**,
  KEY `Index_5` (`KIND`) **USING BTREE**,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_challenges_1` FOREIGN KEY (`OWNER_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_challenges_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SOLVEDREPLAY_ID`) REFERENCES `uploads` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Index_3 and Index_5 is using btree (between the ** **, I couldnt make it bold), but interestingly the others arent. All index is "BTREE", I just dont understand why is it emphasize in the CREATE TABLE expression

Comment: how did you create the table?

Comment: Actually I used MySQL Query browser, which allows me to create fields "visually" in kind

Answer (score 5):

It means that your indices are using a B-tree model under-the-hood, as opposed to a hashmap.

A B-tree is a generalisation of a binary tree. They are good for inequalities (`<`, `>`), ranges and ordering. Hashmaps do not support those things, but are faster for equal/not-equal checks. I'm not sure which performs better for a small enum set like you have for KIND.

The default is BTREE anyway, so those statements are just being explicit.

Here is a good reference for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: B-tree is rather a generalization of a binary search tree.

Comment: "The default is BTREE anyway, so those statements are just being explicit." and thats why I dont understand why its marked there - whereas its not appearing

Comment: It just depends on what added the index; some things add it and some don't. For some reason the DB remembers whether each thing was explicitly specified (it may even remember all the statements which modified the table and simply merge them together)

Answer (score 1):

A btree is data structure.

It is a good way of indexing data.

Perhaps google Btree

Comment: "The default is BTREE anyway, so those statements are just being explicit." and thats why I dont understand why its marked there - whereas its not appearing